# crash while building notification : RemoteServiceException

Tags: android, push-notification, crash, crashlytics, remoteserviceexception

In my app, we are showing one notification which do have 2 or 3 action button.

I'm getting crashes on crashlytics for some devices which incldes Blackberry, Asus, HTC< HUAWEI, Quanta, Oppo, Vivo, Samsung, Yu, MicroMaxx, OnePlus, Lenovo, iTel, Royal, etc so many devices

Please note that it is not crashing for every devices. I've tried on more than 6 devices and it is working fine but crashing on some devices, mostly Hisense manufacturer.

Crash reason:

```
Fatal Exception: android.app.RemoteServiceException: Bad notification posted from package net.AppName: Couldn't expand RemoteViews for: StatusBarNotification(pkg=net.AppName user=UserHandle{0} id=1536490752 tag=null score=0 key=0|net.AppName|1536490752|null|10115: Notification(pri=0 contentView=net.AppName/0x109007e vibrate=null sound=default defaults=0x1 flags=0x10 color=0x00000000 actions=3 vis=PRIVATE))
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1469)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5270)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:915)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:710)
```

Notification builder code I'm using is :

```
var mBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
          .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.resources, R.drawable.in_ic_icon_v4))
          .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.in_ic_notification_icon_v4)
          .setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.msg_new_account))
          .setContentText(body)
          .setStyle(NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(body))
          .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
          .setAutoCancel(true)

 mBuilder.addAction(-1, skip, getPendingIntent(getIntentForAction(context, skipBundle), context, requestCode))
 mBuilder.addAction(-1, skip, getPendingIntent(getIntentForAction(context, skipBundle), context, requestCode))
 val mNotificationManager = context.applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
 mNotificationManager.notify(id, mBuilder.build())
```

It is throwing RemoteServiceException. The irony is that I don't have any RemoteView in Notification. Can someone help me in this?

Is it something related to icon size? I'm using pngs and max size is 20kb(for xxhdpi). also I've read somewhere that .setStyle(NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(body)) can cause the problem, is it so?

Comment: check this link - https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Android-SDK/issues/263

Comment: what `PendingIntent` are you using for your notification?

Comment: @pskink I'm using 
    `PendingIntent.getService(context, requestCode, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT)` as pending intent

Comment: so post that service code as you are getting `RemoteServiceException`

Comment: @pskink which service you are talking about. ^ call is on PendingIntent. getService() is static method of PendingIntent class

Comment: your service, the code that `intent` is pointing to

Comment: @pskink I don't understand why does that matter? crash is happening when notification is getting created with message : Couldn't expand RemoteViews.

Comment: sorry: yes indeed, i missed that `Couldn't expand RemoteViews` message

Comment: @pskink oh ok. so any idea why it is crashing even I don't have RemoteViews?

Comment: @v.y. not working. I'm getting same exception but for different reason : `Couldn't expand RemoteViews`. that too when I'm not using RemoteViews in notification at all.